# how to make the user text field value to float in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a input box and i want that when user enter 3 then it show 3.00 in text not 3 while he enters data.We normally do tofixed for variable upto 2 digits but how to show that if user enter any data 4 then it should be in textfield 4.00

For lets say user enter data any number but it should show in float in same textfields mean 3 to 3.00 5 to 5.00 like this

```
<HTML>
<body>

 <input type="text" value=""/>

 <script>
  var a =4
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

then it should be in text field like 4.00

Comment: You mean as the user is typing a number in the text field it automatically changes to a float even though the user is still typing?

Comment: @ArnelleBalane when user finshes typing then it should show float

Comment: You should read [this](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: @xyu can you please edit here i am new to jquerry

Comment: Edit what? And if you're new to jquery this task(the one in your question) is a good one for a starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickly do this with the following:

```
$('input').change(function(){
   this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2); 
});
```

**[Here's a demo on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/zrMxy/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='text']").blur(function() {
  var value = parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
  $(this).attr("value", value.toFixed(2));
});
```

I'm assuming that a user is done typing when he removes the focus (click out, etc) of the text field.

Comment: you should use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')` else or it won't work with jQuery 1.9